# Why does Entity Framework Core 2.2 C# respond with an error while inserting a new entity with an existing nested entity

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am working on a ASP.NET Core 2.2 project and I am using Entity Framework Core 2.2 as the ORM for accessing an Azure SQL database.

I have the following two entities/tables which are related to eachother (One-To-Many relationship).

```
[Table("Users")]
public class UserEntity : BaseGuidEntity
{
    .../// other properties

    [ForeignKey("Language")]
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }

    public virtual UserLanguageEntity Language { get; set; }
}

[Table("UserLanguages")]
public class UserLanguageEntity
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ..//other properties
    public virtual ICollection<UserEntity> Users { get; set; }
}
```

I have two different languages already inserted in the database. These two are the only available languages, and no new languages are allowed to be inserted. I use the following code to insert a new user with the related language:

```
var language = _languageRepository.GetById(newUser.Language.Id);

        newUser.LanguageId = language.Id;
        newUser.Language = language;

        _userRepository.Insert(newUser);
```

So, I basically want to create a new user with the related existing language as well. But what entity framework core attempts, is creating a new language entity with the already existing values, which will ofcourse cause errors in the SQL db.

> Error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert 
>   explicit value for identity column in table 'UserLanguages' when 
>   IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

How can I related an existing language record to a new user entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried not to set newUser.Language? There should be no reason for you to do that since you have set LanguageId. Your GetById method `_languageRepository.GetById(newUser.Language.Id);` has probably disposed of the context and Insert method is registering that Language object that you are setting and trying to insert it.

Here is how I retrieve entities in my generic repo, maybe this can help you:

```
public IEnumerable<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereCondition, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = _dbContext.Set<T>().Where(whereCondition);

        if (includes.Any())
            return Includes(includes, query);

        return query;
    }

protected IQueryable<T> Includes(Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes, IQueryable<T> query)
    {
        return includes.Aggregate(query, (current, includeProperty) => current.Include(includeProperty));
    }
```

And then you can use it like:

```
FindBy(r => r.Id == id, incl => incl.Languages)
```

Comment: This will work, but then when I use the following with the include properties: var user = _userRepository.GetFirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == newUser.Id, "Language,andsomeotherfields"), all other related entities will be filled except Language. So somehow EF Core can't related the LanguageId I have inserted earlier to the UserLanguageEntity record in the database.

Comment: Can you paste the code that you are using when retrieving the user?

Comment: Sure:

public TEntity GetFirstOrDefault(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter, string includeProperties)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(includeProperties))
            {
                foreach (string includeProperty in includeProperties.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                {
                    Entities.Include(includeProperty);
                }
            }
            return Entities.FirstOrDefault(filter);
        }

Comment: Just as I wanted to test and debug it, my project is acting weird. When starting it, the program automatically stops: The program '[15188] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'. So I am attempting to fix this before I can test your recommended code!

Comment: In my experience restarting the machine usually helps :D

Comment: Very weird, but even my solution suddenly works now with my own GetFirstOrDefault method. And also your solution works. Haha I am so confused now. But anyway, thanks for your help! Both solutions work, and suddenly so does mine as well, which didn't work before (...)